# jQuery, handling actions listeners on table cells, dealing with performance and memory leaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, memory-leaks, html-table

In my HTML/JS application, I generate table elements depending on some rules and user actions dynamically on the runtime. I generate the content of the table by string addition and finally set it to a container using Jquery **.html()** method. AFAIK, Jquery handles itself memory issues and makes some more detailed stuff better than setting the innerHTML directly. Depending on the user actions, on the next phase, a totally different table is generated and set to same main container again. The container remains stable and the html of the container is updated dynamically with new tables.

My question is about registering event listeners and handling memory leaks and performance, because on desktop it runs fine, but on IPAD or Android tablets, after some actions, or after some login/logoff, the application becomes slowly, sometimes freezes and becomes unresponsive and the device does not respond to click actions anymore. I think of memory leaks or performance issues and plan to debug using google chrome, but first I want to learn whether there is a flaw in the design.
I have 3 options for handling event listeners in my mind, currently I am using the first one:

*1.option* (currently used)

```
// generate whole content with string addition and set by html()

var content = '<table id="t1"><tr><td>val1</td><td>val2</td><td>vall3</td>..</table>';
content += '<script>registerListeners("t1")</script>';
$('#mainContainer').html(content);

// will be called when table is set to DOM
function registerListeners(id) {
    $('#t1').find('td').bind("click",function() { 
         cellClicked($(this[0]);});
    }

function cellClicked(domCell) { // }
```

As you see, on each table, when the table is generated in DOM after setting the html of mainContainer, the registerListener method is called, which binds
the cellClicked action for each cell. In my app, I can use same cellClicked action for all table cells for all possible tables. 
I do not perform any cleanup (call empty to mainContent or invoke unbind), when a new table is to be set, i simply generate a new table content and set directly to the main content by

```
$('#mainContent').html(newTableContent);
```

And registerListeners method is called for the cells again. If there is N table update is to be performed, registerListeners will be called N times. What happened to previous listeners? Possible leak or performance issue?

*2.option*

I generate the table cells with actions registered, without calling any bind method:

```
var content = '<table id="t1"><tr><td onclick='cellClicked(this)'>val1</td>..';

$('#mainContainer').html(content);

function cellClicked(domCell) { // }
```

And again when a new table is to be generated, it is generated by string addition and calling html() to the container.

*3.option (planned)*

As I see in SO, it is better to use the **on** method for dynamically generated elements, I will generate the table as option 1, but do not call any registerListener method. I only call the register method only 1 time at startup, even if there is no table exists.

```
// call only once at startup
$('#mainContent').on('click','.cellclass',function() { //handle cell click

 var content = '<table id="t1"><tr><td class="cellclass">val1</td><td>val2..</table>';
 $('#mainContainer').html(content);
```

And when logoff is to performend, call off

```
$('#mainContent').off('click','.cellclass');
```

What is your suggestion between the 3 options or advice different options, when we have frequently updating tables with 20 columns and 30-40 rows for example, to prevent memory leaks and keep up with the performance?

Answer (score 3):

Consider how many table cells you are creating.  A 10x10 table will require 100 event handlers.  They add up quick.  A better option is to have a single handler on the containing object.  Your handler would then determine what exactly received the event and take appropriate action.

With jQuery you do this via a delegated event.  Something like

```
$('#mytable-container').on('click', 'td', function(e) { // event logic });
```

"this" inside the function is the object that received the event - the 'td' tag in this case.  Or you could use the e.target to do further analysis.  Using data-XXX attributes on your TDs to hold any specific data also helps a good deal.  (i.e. data-id="my-db-id")  You could then do $(this).data('id') to get the "my-db-id" value from within the event handler.

I had a similar problem as you back in the IE6 days, and getting rid of the extra handlers did the trick for me.  That may not be the silver bullet you need though.  There may still be other issues going on, but this is a good start.

Comment: Your suggestion is close to option 3. Which is better using class selector or tag selector? It is better for me using a class selector because i do not want to register the listener for all cells in the table, some of them will not listen to clicks. And in the app, the mainContainer will not include always tables, sometimes it will include many buttons, textfields etc.  I will use same mechanism for textfields for example, $('#mainContent').on('focus','.textfieldclass',function() { //handle focus

Comment: In a case like that I would make my handler a little more like a router to sub handlers.  something like "determine what was clicked.  switch based on what was clicked, to call an appropriate sub-function to handle that click".  Determining what was clicked is up to you.  IDs, classes, and tag names are all valid approaches.  So is inspecting your data attributes to figure out what you need to do.  That could be as simple as if ($(this).hasClass('doit)) { doitFunction(); }, or if ($(this).data('objecttype') == 'person') { handlePerson(this); }.

Comment: Hmm you mean instead of $('#mainContent').on('click','.class1', callback1) $('#mainContent').on('click','.class2', callback2) it will better $('#mainContent').on('click','.commonclass',callback) and in the callback check whether to invoke callback1 or callback2. Moreover, only registering click, focus, move event listeners to our mainContent and then routing the events to subhandlers. (Not registering multiple click listeners to mainContent). Is it better for performance?

Comment: Determining how performant means comparing before/after measurements.  Normally though having a single handler takes less RAM.  If you need to get into twisted logic within that handler, then either breaking your code into sub functions, or making use of other handlers may be a better choice.  It all depends on what you are doing.  A simple `if ($(this).has('.someclass')) { // do something }` isn't really a performance concern though.  It moves any performance impacts to when the user initiates the event - not when loading the page, so is not usually an issue.